# How to make ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag inherit methods from Tag model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using acts-as-taggable-on 2.0.6 for tagging in a Rails 3.0.9 app. I've successfully added db-backed attributes to the Tag model, for example each tag has an RSS feed so I can call `@post.tags.first.feed_url` to grab the feedburner URL from my database.

But while I can add attributes to the Tag model, it seems I can't add instance methods. I created the instance method:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def subscribable?
    !feed_url.blank?
  end
  ...
end
```

But when I call `@post.tags.first.subscribable?` I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `subscribable?' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x00000100d32290>
```

Is there a way to tell `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` objects to inherit model methods from the `Tag` model?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this `/config/initializers/tag_monkey_patch.rb`

```
class ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
  def subscribable?
    !feed_url.blank?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering the exact same thing. As far as i've tried, it isn't working for me..

```
class Tag < ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
   def total_count
     ...
   end
end
```

When I call it in a dirty chained form example, like so:

```
my_model.my_instance.tag_counts_on(:tags).first.total_count
```

I get a

```
undefined method `total_count' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "first">
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you shouldn't be declaring a new "Tag" model like this, but should should be overriding the class like this:

```
class ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
   def total_count
      ...
   end
end
```

Comment: Your answer looked like it would work, but when I replace `class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base` with `class ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` I still get undefined method for instance methods I've added, as above.

Comment: Where are you overriding the class? You can try putting it in your initializers to make sure it's getting applied on server start up.

Comment: I need the Tag model (and controller, views, etc.) so that users can edit a tag in order add the feed_url attribute I mentioned earlier. It was in the model that I replace `class Tag` with `class ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag`, or `class ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag < ActiveRecord::Base`, neither of which let me attach instance methods to ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag objects.

Comment: I don't think ActsAsTaggable looks for the class in the Models directory, so you should rather add it to the initializers to make sure it gets applied on start up.